# Processing results from plpgsql function

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

I have PostgreSQL function witch returns this json array as text:

```
[{"seq_no":5796,"start_date":null,"end_date":"2008-09-30 12:32:28","geom_change":"Y"}, 
 {"seq_no":8235,"start_date":"2008-09-30 12:32:28","end_date":"2008-10-02 16:43:24","geom_change":"N"}, 
 {"seq_no":9306,"start_date":"2008-10-02 16:43:24","end_date":"2008-10-02 18:31:09","geom_change":"N"}, 
 {"seq_no":9754,"start_date":"2008-10-02 18:31:09","end_date":"2008-10-07 17:08:25","geom_change":"N"}, 
 {"seq_no":10701,"start_date":"2008-10-07 17:08:25","end_date":"2008-10-08 15:17:48","geom_change":"N"}, 
 {"seq_no":8940,"start_date":"2008-10-08 15:17:48","end_date":"2008-10-08 15:51:47","geom_change":"N"}, 
 {"seq_no":12500,"start_date":"2008-10-08 15:51:47","end_date":"2008-10-08 17:34:35","geom_change":"N"}, 
 {"seq_no":13079,"start_date":"2008-10-08 17:34:35","end_date":"2008-10-08 17:56:03","geom_change":"N"}]
```

I want to use this data to select **seq_no** filtered by start/end dates. A preferred result would be table like this.

```
seq_no   start_date             end_date               geom_change
------------------------------------------------------------------
5796     NULL                   2008-09-30 12:32:2     Y
8235     2008-09-30 12:32:28    2008-10-02 16:43:24    N
```

Or maybe there is simpler way to use this data to select seq_no between start_date and end_date?

Comment: Sorry, I downvoted because this question does not show any research effort. What have you tried yourself so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast your result as `jsonb` and then use the jsonb functions and operators along with a tzrange as follows:

```
with indata (jdata) as (
  values (
'[{"seq_no":5796,"start_date":null,"end_date":"2008-09-30 12:32:28","geom_change":"Y"}, 
 {"seq_no":8235,"start_date":"2008-09-30 12:32:28","end_date":"2008-10-02 16:43:24","geom_change":"N"}, 
 {"seq_no":9306,"start_date":"2008-10-02 16:43:24","end_date":"2008-10-02 18:31:09","geom_change":"N"}, 
 {"seq_no":9754,"start_date":"2008-10-02 18:31:09","end_date":"2008-10-07 17:08:25","geom_change":"N"}, 
 {"seq_no":10701,"start_date":"2008-10-07 17:08:25","end_date":"2008-10-08 15:17:48","geom_change":"N"}, 
 {"seq_no":8940,"start_date":"2008-10-08 15:17:48","end_date":"2008-10-08 15:51:47","geom_change":"N"}, 
 {"seq_no":12500,"start_date":"2008-10-08 15:51:47","end_date":"2008-10-08 17:34:35","geom_change":"N"}, 
 {"seq_no":13079,"start_date":"2008-10-08 17:34:35","end_date":"2008-10-08 17:56:03","geom_change":"N"}]'::jsonb
 )
)
select (j->>'seq_no')::int as seq_no, 
       (j->>'start_date')::timestamp as start_date, 
       (j->>'end_date')::timestamp as end_date,
       j->>'geom_change' as geom_change
  from indata  i
       cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(jdata) as e(j)
 where tsrange((j->>'start_date')::timestamp, (j->>'end_date')::timestamp, '[]') @> '2008-09-30 12:32:28'::timestamp;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1187df08bdfc0b5f77051b2fcc81ac5b)*

Comment: No specific need for datatype jsonb, json also works, just use json_array_elements()